# Why the need to call static voids from other static voids?

Tags: java, static, void

I have a Computer Programming-K course at my high school, and we use Java as our language. I noticed that you seem to NEED to have the `public *static* void main(String[] args)` at the beginning of every script. Our main structure is this:

```
public class
   ( void main()
     void input()
     void process()
     void output() )
```

And we have to make all void methods static, to be able to call one another, because we can't use a non-static main. Why? What does static mean in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, `main` being declared as `public static void` is mandated by the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4):

> The method `main` must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of `String`.

That's simply the way it is; without it, Java will not execute your script due to there being a lack of a main method.

It also doesn't matter *where* you put it - it could be in the middle of that class, at the top, at the bottom, or in a completely different file - so long as your program has a `main` method for it to actually run.

As for the meaning of `static` - well, that depends on the context.

- If you're using `static` on a field (that is, a variable contained in a class), then there will [only ever be one instance of that field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1).
- If you're using `static` on a method (like `main`, or another method), then that is a [class method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2), and does not require an instance of the object for it to be invoked and used.  These particular methods shouldn't rely on the internal state of the class in which they're being invoked.

As an example, you'll get into a discussion about `Integer.parseInt` sometime later; this is a static method, which is tied to `Integer`, which doesn't require an instance of an `Integer` to invoke.

Next, don't think that the declaration of `static` methods is going to be commonplace for your code.  To be frank, that represents purely procedural programming (that is, defining methods to do these specific things with no regard to state, instead of an object-oriented design that *may* or may not take into account state).

The only time you're ever forced to declare something to be static is if you're using it within a static context yourself.  Since you don't create an instance of your class (through the `new` keyword), you won't be able to use any of the methods you've declared in it.

This will not compile, as `main` doesn't have a way to reference that method.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        invokeBar();
    }

    public void invokeBar() {
        System.out.println("Yay, bar!");
    }
}
```

The below *will* compile, since `main` does have a way to directly invoke that method:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        invokeBar();
    }

    public static void invokeBar() {
        System.out.println("Yay, bar!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh. I see now, so static is just a way of saying, 'This is the ONLY instance of this method'?

Comment: Remember the context.  If it's a field, then there's only one instance of that field.  If it's a method, then the method doesn't require that there be an instance of the object it's attached to for it to be invoked (e.g. [Integer#parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))).

Answer (score 0):

Static means that you do not need to have an instance of a class in order to call that method.

`static void main`  is just the specific function that Java requires, so that it knows where to begin running your code. Every program must contain one, and exactly one, `static void main`.

Answer (score 0):

**I noticed that you seem to NEED to have the 'public static void main(String[] args)' at the beginning of every script.**

The reason for this is that when JVM runs your program it needs to be able to run it without creating an instance of your entry class containing main method. Sometimes your class containing main method may have constructors which needs arguments to create an instance of it then how would JVM know what values does it have to pass to create an instance of it on its own, which is why java forces you to make main as static method so that JVM doesnot need to worry about creating an instance of your main class to call the main method which is the entry point to your application.

**And we have to make all voids static**

This is an incorrect assumption. You need not make your void methods as static. There are 2 ways of calling your methods either through object of the class (these methods are called instance methods) or through the class variable(name) (these methods are called static methods). If you donot want to make your methods static then you need to create an instance of you class ad call your methods.

**What does static mean in Java?**
static is a modifier in Java . You can either use it for your instance variables or for methods or for inner classes. This keyword makes the resource(instance variables/methods/innerclass) a property of the underlying class and hence is shared across all the instances(objects) of the class.